# Calculate total amount from different dropdowns selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate the total value of the selected value. In one row I have three options one is to select room that is one only, second is to select any one option and the same with the third column. When I am selecting options, it shows the correct "total Amount". Also on clicking on add room one new row with same options appears and there is no limit to add rows. But now what I am trying to do is When someone select values from different rows, "Total Amount" must show the total selected values.

Suppose, I have selected 1 room, 1st value is 5000 and 2nd value is 4000, then "Total Amount" is showing 9000. When I added one more row, in this again I selected 1 room, the 1st value is 6000 and the 2nd value is 9000. Now the " Total Amount" will show 24000 and this will work continuously on adding rows and selecting values.

Here is my HTML :

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tr style=" color: white;">
        <th class="col-md-4 text-center" style="padding: 10px;">No. of Rooms : </th>
        <th class="col-md-4 text-center" style="padding: 10px;">Adult's : </th>
        <th class="col-md-4 text-center" style="padding: 10px;">Extra : </th>
    </tr>
</table>                        

<table id="dataTable" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td >
            <select name="links" class="form-control person-3" action="post" id="myselect" onChange="document.getElementById('rooms').innerHTML = this.value;">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td >
            <select name="keywords" class="form-control person-1" action="post" id="myselect" onChange="document.getElementById('adults').innerHTML = this.value;">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                <option value="5000">1</option>
                <option value="8000">2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td >
            <select name="violationtype" class="form-control person-2" action="post" id="myselect" onChange="document.getElementById('extra').innerHTML = this.value;">
                <option value="0" selected="selected">No Beds</option>
                <option value="4000">Adult</option>
                <option value="3000">Child below 12</option>
                <option value="2000">Child below 7</option>
            </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table> 

<input type="button" value="Add Rooms" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 15px;" /><br><br>



    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="color: white;font-size: 20px;text-align: right;">Total Amount :</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="color: white;font-size: 20px;text-align: left;"> 
            <span class="addition"></span>
        </div>
    </div><br>
```

Here is my script through which I am calculating the total amount:

```
var add_1 =0;
var add_2 = 0; 
var mul_3 = 0;

function displayValues() {
  add_1 = parseInt($('.person-1').val());
  add_2 = parseInt($('.person-2').val());
  mul_3 = parseInt($('.person-3').val());

  $(".addition-1").text(add_1);
  $(".addition-2").text(add_2);
  $(".multiplication_3").text(mul_3);

  $(".addition").text( mul_3 *( add_1 + add_2) );


}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".person-1").change(displayValues); 
    $(".person-2").change(displayValues);
    $(".person-3").change(displayValues);
});
```

Here is the code to add rooms:

```js
function addRow(tableID) {

  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    //alert(newcell.childNodes);
    switch (newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
      case "text":
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
        break;
      case "checkbox":
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
        break;
      case "select-one":
        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not work. The elements with id's `rooms`, `adults` and `extra` are all missing, and the function `addRow()` also does not exist. Please update your code, Also providing a SlackBlitz/JSFiddle would also be helpful.

Comment: Sorry i missed that, now i have added. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete Code............. and existing has so many errors..

Try to make it work out .but  addRow('dataTable'); defination missing.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/756tb80f/6/`
```

Comment: Sorry i missed that, now i have added. Please check now.

Comment: Please check this link

Comment: i don't know why room is not added on Js fiddle, but it working fine on my localhost. Here is my fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/Bhawesh7731/b1jf6gqz/13/

Answer (score 0):

does this help?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var dd1 =0;
    var dd2 =0;
    var dd3 =0;
    var totalBillAmt = 0;
  
  $("#myselect1").change(function(){    dd1 = Number($(this).val());  updateTotalPrice();  });
  $("#myselect2").change(function(){    dd2 = Number($(this).val());  updateTotalPrice();  });
  $("#myselect3").change(function(){    dd3 = Number($(this).val());  updateTotalPrice();  });


  updateTotalPrice = function (){
    totalBillAmt = dd1 + dd2 + dd3;
    $("#totalPrice").text("total amount is:" + totalBillAmt);
  };
  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr style=" color: white;">
                        <th class="col-md-4 text-center" style="padding: 10px;">No. of Rooms : </th>
                        <th class="col-md-4 text-center" style="padding: 10px;">Adult's : </th>
                        <th class="col-md-4 text-center" style="padding: 10px;">Extra : </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>                        

                <table id="dataTable" style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <select name="links" class="form-control person-3" action="post" id="myselect1" >
                                <option value="0" >--select--</option>
                                <option value="100">test option 1</option>
                                <option value="500">test option 2</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <select name="keywords" class="form-control person-1" action="post" id="myselect2" >
                                <option value="0" >--select--</option>
                                <option value="5000">another opt 1</option>
                                <option value="8000">another opt 2</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <select name="violationtype" class="form-control person-2" action="post" id="myselect3" >
                                <option value="0" >No Beds</option>
                                <option value="4000">Adult</option>
                                <option value="3000">Child below 12</option>
                                <option value="2000">Child below 7</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </table> 

                <input type="button" value="Add Rooms" onclick="updateTotalPrice()" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 15px;" /><br><br>
<div id='totalPrice'></div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6" style="color: white;font-size: 20px;text-align: right;">Total Amount :</div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" style="color: white;font-size: 20px;text-align: left;"> 
                            <span class="addition"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div><br>
```

Comment: now i have added the code to add rooms. Please check now.

Comment: Did you run the code i pasted... it is adding the rooms as soon as they are selected...

Comment: not working. Showing the error   {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: addRow is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 48,
  "colno": 138
}

Comment: the program calculated the values as soon as the dropdown changed... I simply replaced the deleted AddRow function call with the new function call - hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have same ID "**myselect**" for all select tag. Please give them unique IDs otherwise they'll misbehave. 
Then if you are getting values from the class name what will be the case when one more row is added with same class names. Your logic will not work. Please try getting values with dynamic Ids provided to the select tag in each row.

Answer (score 0):

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/756tb80f/24/`
```

Please check the above link

Is this what you expected output

Comment: Yes, bro. It was nearly to my requirement. In this, i didn't want to change total amount value on increasing the room number but only when adult or extra value is changed

Comment: No. of room is constant

Comment: Why we have dropdown in add Room

Comment: `https://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/756tb80f/26/`

please check the link

Comment: you have made changes on adults, i didn't want that